# 301 redirect with RewriteRules

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, http-headers

I have a problem concerning RewriteRules.
I'd like to move one page permanently, so I want to use a 301 redirect. I tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^page1/([A-Z].*)$ http://www.abs.nl/page1/vraag-$1 [R=301]
```

However this does not work. Can someone please tell me how I could fix this? I already tried for hours to find an answer.

Should I also use a %{HTTP_HOST} condition? I see this a lot but I don't know how it works.

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

1. Make sure that you have `RewriteEngine On` before your rewrite rule.
2. Your current regex is looking for a capital letter followed by any character, is this what you want?

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^page/(.*)$ http://www.abs.nl/page1/vraag-$1 [R=301,L]
```

That redirect will match on any string of characters following page/ in a URL.